# Factor $x^2+10x+15$?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

How can you factor $x^2+10x+15$? The form $Ax^2+Bx+C$, where $B$ is the sum of $2$ factors of $C$ (and $\lvert A\rvert=1$) does not work.

Comment: You need the roots to factor a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: $x^2+10x+15=(x+5)^2-10$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
x^2+10x+15=(x^2+10x+25)-10=(x+5)^2-(\sqrt{10})^2.
$$
Now use, $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: Thanks very much! I knew there was some stupid trick that turns into a difference of perfect squares, I just couldn't find it. :)

Comment: @JacobWheeler : Notice that what is done here is _completing the square_.  That can solve all quadratic equations, and has other uses as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use the quadratic formula:

$$
x_1,_2 = \frac{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} \text{ when }  ax^2 + bx + c = 0
$$

$a=1$,
$b=10$,
$c=15$,

This will get you 2 roots. You could then write your function as:

$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$